# How to bind a private function as a callback

Tags: javascript, binding, this

How do I make a private function of a prototype pattern be the recipient of an event?  So far, I can only do this using a public function as a mediator. Is there a more direct way to do this?

https://plnkr.co/edit/9viJKqdczvfBqgxWG1qW?p=preview

```
var Person = (function() {

    function Person(name) {

        console.log('listening...', $('body')[0])
        this.name = name;
        $('body').on('test', this.onTest.bind(this));
}   

    Person.prototype.onTest = function(evt) {
        _talk.call(this, evt);
    }

    function _talk(evt) {
        console.log(this.name + ' says: ' + evt.payload)
    }

    return Person;
}());



$(function() {
    var p = new Person('Bob');
    $('body').trigger({
        type: 'test',
        payload: 'hello'
    });
})
```

--- EDIT ---

Ok, so I now see that I can do this:

```
    $('body').on('test', function(evt) {
         _talk.call(this, evt);
    }.bind(this));
```

...but it still feels clumsy

Comment: You can't _really_ do that. Sort of. A function is either visible from the outside or not. You could either make it "public" and stick with it or try to make it conditionally public. Somehow. It would boil down to essentially having some sort of `if (inTest)` and exposing the function then. I suppose you could do something funky with a proxy but I feel that would add more complexity and risk than it's worth it. I'd personally just expose the function but others might disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if a function is in the prototype chain of an object, you can bind it anyways.

So there's nothing preventing you from binding the `_talk` function to an instance of `Person`.

```js
var Person = (function() {

    function Person(name) {

        console.log('listening...', $('body')[0])
        this.name = name;
        $('body').on('test', _talk.bind(this));
    }   

    Person.prototype.onTest = function(evt) {
        _talk.call(this, evt);
    }

    function _talk(evt) {
        console.log(this.name + ' says: ' + evt.payload)
    }

    return Person;
}());



$(function() {
    var p = new Person('Bob');
    $('body').trigger({
        type: 'test',
        payload: 'hello'
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```